# How can I create a Chatter Free License user in a test class?

Tags: unit-test, user-record

I am trying to create a user in a test class and this user needs to be a Chatter Free License.
Usertype is the field to set the license but this one is not writable.

Any pointers on creating a user with a specific license type?

Comment: Your title states Chatter Only, but your question mentions Chatter Free, which are different user licenses, I've based my answer on the content of your question.

Comment: Sorry i wanted chatter Free..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The license isn't actually connected to the user, but depends on the profile you assign your user. If you create a user with the Chatter Free User profile, the usertype will be set to Chatter free.

```
5.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG
Execute Anonymous: Profile p = [SELECT id, Name FROM Profile where name = 'Chatter Free User' ].get(0);
Execute Anonymous:   
Execute Anonymous:                  User u = new User(firstname= 'Samuel',
Execute Anonymous:                            lastname='De Rycke',
Execute Anonymous:                            Alias='Samuel',
Execute Anonymous:                            email = 'nospamplz@absi.be',
Execute Anonymous:                            username= 'nospamplz@absi.be', 
Execute Anonymous:                            profileId= p.id, 
Execute Anonymous:                            emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
Execute Anonymous:                            languagelocalekey='en_US',
Execute Anonymous:                            localesidkey='en_US',
Execute Anonymous:                            timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles');
Execute Anonymous:                  insert u;    
Execute Anonymous: 
Execute Anonymous: u = [select usertype from user where id =:u.id];
Execute Anonymous: 
Execute Anonymous: system.debug('--------------------------->User.UserType:'+u.usertype);
13:15:05.040 (40786000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
13:15:05.040 (40800000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
13:15:05.769 (769888000)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|--------------------------->User.UserType:CsnOnly
13:15:05.820 (820554000)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
13:15:05.820 (820567000)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

The CsnOnly type will display as the Chatter Free User License in salesforce.com.